# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el estilo de un botón de HTML desde un documento JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo en un documento HTML un botón con un id:

```
input type="button" id="boton1" '''
```

y en un documento de JavaScript estoy intentando modificar el ancho con el código:

```
var miboton=document.getElementById("boton1");
miboton.style.width="50px";'''
```

la consola me muestra el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null.

Disculpen, soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo programación de un curso en YouTube. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Comment: Agrega tu etiqueta input completa

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes aprender a escribir las preguntas en StackOverflow, procurando que el código quede en formato código para ver bien lo que tu ya has escrito y así poder orientarte mejor.

Por otro lado el problema es  que si tu código es el que hay al principio de tu texto, el HTML está mal escrito.

tu HTML debería ser para crear un botón de dos maneras:

```
<input type="button" id='boton1' value='pulsar'/>
```

o

```
<button type="button" id='boton1'>pulsar</button>
```

luego en el código JS debes llamar al botón.
Tu usas getElementById entonces.

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton1')
boton.style.width= "100.px"
```

Si estás aprendiendo con videos de youtube, te sugiero tener en tus favoritos de tu navegador la página oficial de Mozilla para consultar código y buenas prácticas :
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript

y a título personal también me gusta mucho
[la de W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Comment: Aquí tienes un error **type=button** en el primer ejemplo

Comment: cierto es, seria type="button"

Comment: No hacía falta que me penalizaras con -2.

Comment: Si te refieres a mi entonces te aclaro yo no emití el voto